# administrative checklist on multisite

Tags: wordpress, configuration, multisite

We have a multisite on WP that shares one db.

I am unclear if some settings are universal or if some are unique to each site. I'm referencing: administer > administrative console > configuration checklist.

So for instance, do I need to configure search or display settings for each site or will they inherit the network level site? And also for things like recaptcha and USPS address standardization.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of those settings are set per-site.

If you're more comfortable looking at things at the SQL level, you can check out everything stored in `civicrm_setting`.  Note the presence of a `domain_id` field; each domain ID corresponds to one of the sites (see `civicrm_domain` to map them).

It's pretty safe to use SQL to copy those settings if you need to bulk change them.  There used to be an extension that let you change the settings in bulk; the name escapes me right now, but it doesn't work with modern CiviCRM anyway.